# Property cannot be deserialized because the member 'properties' is not public

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

> The data contract type 'DTO.AccountData' cannot be deserialized because the member 'properties' is not public. Making the member public will fix this error. Alternatively, you can make it internal, and use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute on your assembly in order to enable serialization of internal members - see documentation for more details. Be aware that doing so has certain security implications.

And in my class all member variables are public

```
public class AccountData
{

    public string mdn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    .....
    //other public varibales
    .....       

    public Dictionary<string, string> properties
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

**Update**
I tried  [DataContract] and [DataMember] attribute but doesn't work.

Comment: Did you recompile your solution?

Comment: From the beginning it was `public` and yes I cleaned and recompiled the project

Comment: Did you try to mark the class with the [DataContract] attribute and its serializable members with [DataMember]?

Comment: Yes I tried that also..but doesn't work..

Comment: Ïf you tried so, why your sample doesn't have the whole attributes! :D

Comment: I tried this after you comments but that's not working too. And moreover these attributes are not necessary if you need to deserialized all ivars

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got a copy of an old assembly?  It's highly suspect that data contract serialization is going to fail on a public property (i.e. data contract serialization should be failing a lot in the wild)

Comment: @PeterRitchie I don't understand the idea of old assembly. This property was never private/protected/internal. It was always public from the beginning. Moreover I have cleaned the solution also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `DataContractJsonSerializer` expects your json data as

```
  {"properties":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Valorie"},{"Key":"Month","Value":"May"},{"Key":"Year","Value":"2013"}]}
```

I think using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a good idea to parse json

For more you can check this question [Parse dictionary from json windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15804758/468724)