# Parse dictionary from json windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have two piece of code

**Code1**

```
string json = @"{""properties"":{""name"":""carl""}}";
try
{
    MemoryStream stream = GetMemoryStreamFromString(json);
    Type type = typeof(Person);
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
    object obj = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    Debug.WriteLine(obj);
    Person person = obj as Person;
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}

//And my classes
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public Property properties { set; get; }

    public Person() { }
}

[DataContract]
public class Property
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { set; get; }

    public Property() { }
}
```

**Code2**

```
string json = @"{""properties"":{""name"":""carl""}}";
try
{
    MemoryStream stream = GetMemoryStreamFromString(json);
    Type type = typeof(Person);
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type);
    object obj = serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    Debug.WriteLine(obj);
    Person person = obj as Person;
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ee.Message);
}

//And my class
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string,string> properties { set; get; }

    public Person() { }
}
```

Code1 works fine but Code2 give me the exception. Here is the log

> The data contract type 'ScrollViewExample.Person' cannot be deserialized because the member 'properties' is not public. Making the member public will fix this error. Alternatively, you can make it internal, and use the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute on your assembly in order to enable serialization of internal members - see documentation for more details. Be aware that doing so has certain security implications.

The problem here is that I don't have a structure defined for the `properties` it can have any keys so I can't define a class for it. I'm posting this question because I have a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15630873/468724) and after investigating I found that I can't parse dictionary. So I'm framing my problem into a simpler one so that you guys may give your inputs

Comment: Have you consider using http://json.codeplex.com/ instead of the Framework's serializer?

Comment: No I'm not using it as `DataContractJsonSerializer` works fine for windows-8 and I'm just porting my code to wp8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `DataContractJsonSerializer` expects your json data as

```
  {"properties":[{"Key":"Name","Value":"Valorie"},{"Key":"Month","Value":"May"},{"Key":"Year","Value":"2013"}]}
```

I think using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) is a good idea to parse json